# Scale XZ according to Y position

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to scale all vertices on the XZ axes according to their respective Y position.

Something like XZ Scale * Y Position * input value.

The idea is the higher the vertices are, the further outwards they should be.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be the *Simple Deform > Taper* modifier, which by default uses the object's own space, but can be set to use the origin and axes of any other object, typically an Empty.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you